# Having trouble getting Simplebar.js going

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn my way around this cool plugin called Simplebar, but I can't get it to show even on a demo page. What am I missing?

According to https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar, I only need to reference the simplebar.css, the script, and then add "data-simplebar" to whatever div I wish to be scrollable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div data-simplebar style="background-color: grey; width: 400px;">
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please Add height thencheck

Comment: .simplebar-content{
            overflow: scroll !important; 
        }

Comment: To clarify the comments above, your code is fine. Your `<div>` just doesn't currently have (nor need) a scrollbar, as it will just grow to fit its contents. By giving it a set height or an overflow, you can force it to have scrollbars.

Comment: Also, your `script` tag must be *inside* the `<body> </body>`, or inside the `<head></head>`. Its current location (between `</body>` and `</html>`) is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Added height to your div to fix the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div data-simplebar style="background-color: grey; width: 400px;height:300px;">
         <h1>My First Heading</h1>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
         <p>My first paragraph.</p>
      </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.js">     </script>
       </body>
    </html>`
```

Comment: Hey Anil. I think you're on your way to a good answer here, but please take a second to provide some detail. What did OP do wrong? What did you change? Nobody wants to play a game of spot-the-difference :)

Comment: Hey Tyler .I already Commented telling that add height to the div

Comment: Yes I see that, however it should be part of your answer. That comment could get buried or deleted in the future. Your answer should be able to stand entirely on its own, rather than making people search around the page for details. Simply [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54040677/edit) and add your comment to it :)

Comment: Also, if you're going to edit your question, consider fixing the bottom `<script>` tag to move it inside the `</body>` tag, as its currently in an invalid location.